# Model validation with viewModel don't works

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-2

I use viewModels to communicate between my controller and my view.
To get model validation, i use a partial class like this :

```
[MetadataType(typeof(EvaluationValidation))]
public partial class Evaluation
{
    public class EvaluationValidation
    {
        [DisplayName("Title of evaluation")]
        [Required( ErrorMessage="Please give a title")]
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The Displayname is binded to view with no problem but when i try to submit the view, i get this error :

> The model item passed into the
>   dictionary is of type
>   'FOOBAR.Models.Evaluation',
>   but this dictionary requires a model
>   item of type
>   'FOOBAR.Areas.Evaluation.ViewModels.EvaluationFormViewModel'.

This is the code used in my controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(FormCollection formValues)
    {
        Models.Evaluation data = new Models.Evaluation();
        if (TryUpdateModel(data, "evaluations"))
        {
            this.daoe.Create(data);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(data);
    }
```

And this is my viewModel

```
public class EvaluationFormViewModel
{
    public FOOBAR.Models.Evaluation evaluations;
    public SelectList selectlist_evaluationtypes { get; set; }
    public SelectList selectlist_evaluationstatus { get; set; }
}
```

Have you got an idea ?
Thank's by advance

Comment: I am new to ASP.NET MVC but from what I can see you are passing the evaluation object rather than the ViewModel into your view which it is not expecting (strongly typed view?)

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a `Models.Evaluation` instance to your view, which is bound to a model of another type.

```
Models.Evaluation data = new Models.Evaluation();
if (TryUpdateModel(data, "evaluations"))
{
   // ...
}
return View(data);
```

If `TryUpdateModel` returns `false` (which happens when the form does not pass validation, for example), you are effectively passing `data` to the View, which is of type `Models.Evaluation`.

Try mapping it to type `FOOBAR.Areas.Evaluation.ViewModels.EvaluationFormViewModel` before passing it to the view.

Comment: Hm, in fact, i was just trying to pass a business object where i need a viewModel... Sometimes, it's better to stop everything and to wait for a fresh view ^^